# SUM of two columns from same table

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sum

I have a table called `ITEM_MASTER` as

```
ITEM
LEVEL
```

LEVEL can be 1 or 2.

I want to find the count difference of level 2 items from level 1 items.

```
SUM = Level2 Items - Level1 Items
```

Comment: Just to be clear - you're looking for a mathematical difference? E.g., if there are 100 level2 items and 60 level1 items, you'd want to get 40?

Comment: Yes, I need the count difference.

Comment: @ImranHemani Welcome to SO or sort of ... Please read for your future questions ... :) http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One neat trick to do this is to count level2 items as positives and level1 items as negatives with a `case` expression:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE level WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END)
FROM   item_master
```

EDIT:
The above query assumes that `level` can only be 1 or 2. If this is not true, you'd have to handle it within the `case` expression:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE level WHEN 2 THEN 1 WHEN 1 THE -1 END)
FROM   item_master
```

Answer (score 1):

One easy query would be

```
select (select sum(item) from table where level = 1) - (select sum(item) from table where level = 2) from dual
```